# Wordpress blog theme modification

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using [Primal wordpress](https://wordpress.org/themes/primal/) theme for the purpose of a simple blogging website.

I want to make a minor change on the home page. I want to remove the "Date, user and comment" line displayed below the title of the each post. I am not able to remove that from the dashboard. Kindly suggest solution. Suggest steps if it requires plug-in modifications. 
[I want to remove text highlighted in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1RWs.png)

Comment: You have remove it from file or with filter. First Please go through this. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

go to your \wp-content\themes\primal\template-parts\content-single.php

then find the code and comment it

```
  <!--div class="entry-meta">
                <span class="date-structure">               
                    <span class="dd"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></span> 
                </span>
                <?php primal_author(); ?>
                <?php primal_comments_meta(); ?> 
                <?php primal_edit() ?>
            </div--><!-- .entry-meta -->
```

then save the file

It will work for you.

Thanks